Which variety of blueberry is best for jam?
Which blueberry makes the most flavorful jam:  the small wild blueberries or the larger variety?  Wild ones are supposed to have more flavor, but because they have a greater skin to pulp ratio, I wonder if the jam would be fibrous. Flavorful is not subjective.  If something has a lot of flavor, that is universally detected.  If something has little flavor, that too is universally detected.  Also, my comment about the small berries potentially changing the texture from jammy to fibrous is not subjective.

The small ones tatse best, IMHO, so they make the best jam, pie, or any other blueberry product, IMHO, because they taste better. If you don't want skins you can always make jelly instead. But I doubt there's a non-opinion based objective answer to "best for jam."

While interesting, this question feels opinion-based.  Please add criteria to make it answerable in a determinative way.

I edited the question to most flavorful.

I see your edit, but it's better if you add other details: how do you usually make your jam, are you planning to add pectin/sugar/etc? What other characteristics do you look for in the 'best jam'?

Thank you, Luciano, but those are the only questions I had.  It was more a question of strength of flavor and texture.  So, best flavor was clearly not a good choice or wording.  I was hoping to find which had the strongest flavor--regardless of whether someone thinks the flavor is good or bad.  I'll have to work on my word choice.  Thanks again.  (I ended up trying a mix of the two.  It came out highly flavorful, with a smooth texture.)

In general with fruits I find that the bigger size, made to appeal the buyer's eyes, is achieved at the expense of taste. The fruit has just more water and not most sugar/taste.
Since the purpose of making a jam is to evaporate water and concentrate sugars, you'd better go with a starting point which is not so water rich.

Not sure where you are located and what is available to you but I wanted to point out that there are slightly different berries that in common parlance are all called blueberries.
What you can usually get in supermarkets are North American blueberries. These can be more than 1cm in diameter and are white inside.
What you can find in European forests and if you are lucky on markets are technically called bilberries but usually called blueberries as well. These are much smaller, maybe 5mm diameter, fully blue inside and usually softer, prone to breaking. So you will have blue hands if you handled a few. To my knowledge they are not cultivated on a major scale.
If you can get some bilberries, I would recommend these for jams but they are much harder to get.

Maine wild lowbush blueberries are small, and are extensively grown, processed, and marketed worldwide. One would be cautious about using the term cultivated, as that is generally applied to the larger-berry highbush type. The barrens are maintained, in part by burning, but not, as it were, cultivated.
